# Partition key for mutual acquaintances recommendations in CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, partitioning, graph-databases, gremlin

When defining a Graph Database in CosmosDB a Partition Key must be specified. The Partition Key is used for sharding the database. Each partition has a hard storage limit of 10GB. As such queries that do writes or reads across partitions are a lot more expensive. I want to use CosmosDb to find mutual acquaintances that a user has in common in order to suggest possible connections for them to follow. This is in a social network pattern like Twitter or Instagram where the relationships are of the type of "follower" not bi-directional "friends" like Facebook.

The only data that will be stored in the graph is:

- User with 1 property - ID (Vertex)
- Relationship - Follows (Edge)

The queries that will be run against the database are:

- Create User
- Delete User
- Find possible mutual acquaintances

What is an appropriate Partition Key/Structure for a graph problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

Any property to be considered as partition key should have large number of unique values and in social network type scenarios you want to keep user generated content for a particular user in his partition. So ID of the user (a GUID) can be a good partition key.

Comment: You didn't read the question, the only purpose for this graph is to link users, not store any users content. If the ID of the user is used as the partition key every query will cross partitions.

Comment: Actually this is a good suggestion. You could store your data as adjacency lists, this way you can optimize reads with storing edges for a user using the user id as a partition key for the edges. You can't possibly store all of the data in a single partition, and reducing the number of partitions with truncated keys, for example, will not help, because you need to traverse the relations in queries, and those would go to other partitions anyway.